# How to set up enhanced authorisation options in Azure Bot

Tags: azure, authorization, bots

I have an Bot Service in Azure and I would like to ask how to set up enhanced authorization options in DL channel. My target is to be able to call the Bot API only from specific IPs.

Thanks.

Comment: [Configure enhanced authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#configure-enhanced-authentication) and [Direct Line enhanced authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-security-enhanced?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you need: https://cloudacademy.com/lab/securing-public-web-apps-through-frontdoor-using-access-restrictions-advanced-filters/

In this hands-on lab, you will learn how to secure public web app endpoints hosted behind Azure Front Door using advanced access restriction filters.